# Trying to use df.groupby function to group new dataframe according to year information

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I need to use the groupby function to group new dataframe according to year. I have seen other topics on this issue however they don't have it reading from a csv file. I'm wondering am I already doing this right or if I am wrong what is the right way to do this

I tried using

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', usecols= ['price','year'])

df.groupby('price')
print(df)
```

But this gives me back information that is in the image -> [image: groupby result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that in this way:

```
df = df.groupby('year')
```

Print first value in each group:

```
df.first()
```

to get highest `price` for each `year` group:

```
df.groupby('year').max()
```

Or:

```
 df.groupby('year')['price'].max()
```